# Is a 10 point font big enough to use for small descriptions in a cv?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-size

I am creating my CV on an A4 and I am wondering whether a 10 point font size is big enough. here is  screenshot and I am talking about the content next to the crosses: http://d.pr/i/LDKK.

in fact do e really need to have that kind of description in there?

Thanks

Comment: If done well a 10 point is fine, it depends on typeface, spacing, how big a "small description" is, and in your case a background.

Comment: It depends on the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most textbooks will use 10 to 12pt type. 10pt type is generally readable provided the font is well designed and line spacing is appropriate.

(Personal opinion: That san serif text is horrible. Letter spacing is horrendous and it is not a very "readable" typeface to use at a small size. Is that Arial? Arial is a horrid typeface.)

Comment: Im rubbish at typography, can you recommend me which I should use, thanks

Comment: If you want a san serif, stick to what Arial was bastardized from - Helvetica. Other san serifs I like: ClanPro, Myriad, Museo Sans. I, personally, would use a humanist serif typeface for smaller text to improve readability - Stone Informal, Garamond, Goudy. But what you choose really depends upon the overal impression you wish to convey. A serif typeface may not be appropriate if you want a less friendly atmosphere or if delivery is intended on a "screen".

Comment: I would choose Arial over Myriad. To say that a serif is appropriate for a "less friendly atmosphere" would not hold true. Different fonts have different personalities, not all carry the same.

Comment: I was generalizing. And I posted a serif typeface may NOT be appropriate for a less friendly atmosphere. And I'd **never** choose Arial over anything. :)

Comment: In the context of a resume for a GRAPHIC DESIGNER, I'd never suggest going with Arial.

Comment: You are looking at the screen-based rendering of a font that is destined to be printed, and what's more that rendering is heavily hinted (like on a MS Windows system).  So I don't think we're in a position to judge the font.  Furthermore, Arial despite its reputation is not a "Horrible" font, it's a professionally designed font by a renowned designer.  It's also not derived from Helvetica, though its metrics are.  Helvetica in similar conditions (heavily hinted on-screen) is not going to fare much better.  The real test, however is in how it looks printed.

Comment: That said, I agree that using Arial in a CV as a graphic designer may be a poor choice, but mainly because many graphic designers have a grudge against it - as you can see from the above comments.

Comment: I don't have a grudge. I simply dislike the letter spacing, poor, inconsistent, stroke weights, along with other aspects of the font. It is a horrid font in my opinion. No grudge.. just better taste. The downvote based on my (as posted) **opinion** of Arial is a bit harsh. but oh well.

Answer (score 2):

10 point can be perfectly readable, but make sure you validate your design choices by printing your CV. Test on both an inkjet and a laser printer is possible. The kind of printer you're using (inkjet vs laser) can have a big impact on how well smaller type sizes are rendered.

I realize that a printed CV is used less frequently these days, but printing is a great way to get a sense of your overall design. Also, the person you send your CV to might choose to print it out.

Answer (score 1):

When I used to work in print we used the rule that 8pt was the smallest you should go when it comes to copy for print. So 10pt should be fine. It is small, but definitely not illegible.